# Gradle - running a junit test not finding my xml file

Tags: java, spring, junit, build, gradle

I'm having a simple junit test task.

```
task testSanity(type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    def springInstrumentJarPath = project.configurations.compile.find { it.name.startsWith("spring- instrument") }    
    jvmArgs '-javaagent:' + springInstrumentJarPath  
    exclude '**/*TimeBaseTest*'
    exclude '**/*SuiteTests*'
}
```

Problem is i added a new xml file for my ehcache at:

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache.xml
```

And all my test fails since junit is not able to find the file.
How can I define this in the gradle task?

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed by p:configLocation="classpath:/ehcache/ehcache.xml"  and putting the ehcache in src/main/resources/ehcache/ehcache.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/main/webapp` should only contain files that aren't used from Java code (more precisely, files that aren't loaded by a class loader). Java resources should instead go into `src/main/resources`. Hence, moving the file to `src/main/resources/ehcache.xml` should solve the problem.